# Laravel Lumen + Angular .. Same project or not?

Tags: php, angularjs, web-deployment, lumen

I will create a web application using laravel lumen and angular js.
Lumen will be used to create ResftFull webservices and angular js will be used for frontend.

Should i create one project with lumen and angular together? Or its better create a project for backend and other for frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is largely dependent upon how the project is going to be managed and how coupled the front-end is going to be to the back-end.  Typically, it would be best to handle these as 2 separate projects, especially if you have several team members working on each portion separately.  The only time that it would make more sense to include both in a single project would be if the front-end shared a large portion of code with the back-end (mostly seen in NodeJS apps), or when the 2 are so tightly coupled that any changes made to either portion requires changes to the other portion as well.